# Omnet++ 5.0: Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741511”

Tags: omnet++

I have just installed Omnet++ 5.0 (on Windows 7) and installed inet with it as well. As soon as I try to run any of the examples, it throws and error “Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741511”. I am not finding any help regarding this error anywhere. Please help.

Comment: [Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741511](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/bgDRzX-tawc)

Comment: I have installed a fresh copy of Omnet++-5.0 and also inet. It builds successfully and its not my code. The answer you mentioned suggests a misuse of pointer or memory reference but none of the examples is running in my case.

Comment: Which example? What precedes the exit code? Have you tried using a debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: No i did not try to debug.

Starting...

$ cd G:/omnetpp-5.0/samples/inet/examples/ethernet/lans
$ ../../../../../bin/opp_run.exe -r 0 -n ../..;../../../src;../../../tutorials -l ../../../src/INET --debug-on-errors=false omnetpp.ini


Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741511
Working directory: G:/omnetpp-5.0/samples/inet/examples/ethernet/lans
Command line: ../../../../../bin/opp_run.exe -r 0 -n ......./../tutorials -l ../../../src/INET --debug-on-errors=false omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
PATH=;G:/omnetpp-5.0/samples/inet/src;G:\omnetpp-5.0\bin;G:\omnetpp-

Comment: Rao U, have you found a solution? I am facing the same problem